# Live coding on FTP

Tags: ftp-client, livecoding

I have so many sites with different FTP settings. all of them are different like some are word press, drupal, joomla. I mostly have to work on files on FTP, for that i have to first download the latest file then i do the changes and upload again on the ftp. Is there any solution so that i could work live on FTP files without downloading and uploading again and again.

Answer (score 2):

It would help if we knew what computer OS you were using.

For windows, I recommend installing [WinScp](http://winscp.net/eng/download.php). Then install [Notepad++](http://notepad-plus-plus.org/download/v5.9.8.html).

Detailed tutorial here >>>>http://www.thetechrepo.com/main-articles/542-how-to-edit-remote-files-with-winscp-and-notepad-or-any-other-text-editor

**NOTE:** My answer doesn't stop you from downloading and uploading the file, but it makes it feel as if you were editing the files directly on the server.